# In PHP to find the value of a xml node whose slibing has a specific value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an xml file and it contains the following lines:

```
<myphotos_grid grid="true"><![CDATA[<rows>
  <row rowID="1">
    <rowAttribute>
      <theName>photo-name</theName>
      <value/>
    </rowAttribute>
    <rowAttribute>
      <theName>photo-credit</theName>
      <value>my credit</value>
    </rowAttribute>
    <rowAttribute>
      <theName>photo</theName>
      <value>
      <attachment id="1009343343"/>
      </value>
    </rowAttribute>
  </row>
  <row rowID="2">
    <rowAttribute>
      <theName>photo-name</theName>
      <value/>
    </rowAttribute>
    <rowAttribute>
      <theName>photo-credit</theName>
    <value/>
    </rowAttribute>
    <rowAttribute>
      <theName>photo</theName>
      <value>
      <attachment id="4432434344"/>
      </value>
    </rowAttribute>
  </row>
</rows>]]></myphotos_grid>
```

I am reading xml node values through PHP function path. I want to get `<value>` node text value whose `<thename>` sibling node text value is photo-credit. I want to get the photo credit values. Please help me.

PHPcode i tried to parse

```
$this->xpath('myphotos_grid/rows/row/rowattribute/value')
```

but i know my code is wrong as it invloves `CDATA` and it should take value whose slibling node's text value is photo-credit , i am new to this,please help

Comment: wheres your php code?

Comment: You need to create a new XML object with the content of <myphotos_grid grid="true"> because his only one child is a ![CDATA[ value. Then try again with your XPath recipes. If it doesn't works, send us your XPath query string.

Comment: @kevinabelita ,sorry i edited my code

Comment: i don't think this makes sense: `i want to get the VALUE node text whose THENAME sibling node text value is photo-credit`, by using the requirement, you'll get empty, looking at your example, value tags which has siblings of thename tags with photo-credit in it is empty.

Comment: actually what's make sense is the `<theName>photo</theName>` which has a sibling tag of `<value>` which contains a child with values

Comment: @kevinabelita , i  edited my code ,please see the first rowID=1 ,i want to get the "mycredit" in the <value>mycredit</value> whose sibling is <theName>photo-credit</theName>

Comment: There is no `<value>` node in the XML document in your question. Look carefully! (And therfore your question also becomes unclear what you're looking for/asking about [programming wise]).

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'free' the xml within `CDATA` first, then use `xpath()`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(simplexml_load_string($x)); 
// assume your original XML in $x
$credits = $xml->xpath("//rowAttribute[theName = 'photo-credit']/value");
```

Iterate array `$credits` to echo the values:

```
foreach ($credits as $credit) 
    echo $credit . PHP_EOL;
```

See it working: https://eval.in/169617

Answer (score -1):

<del>It's weird that it won't work on the usual thing:</del>

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Use this instead:

```
$xml_string = '<myphotos_grid grid="true"><![CDATA[<rows> <row rowID="1"> <rowAttribute> <theName>photo-name</theName> <value/> </rowAttribute> <rowAttribute> <theName>photo-credit</theName> <value>my credit</value> </rowAttribute> <rowAttribute> <theName>photo</theName> <value> <attachment id="1009343343"/> </value> </rowAttribute> </row> <row rowID="2"> <rowAttribute> <theName>photo-name</theName> <value/> </rowAttribute> <rowAttribute> <theName>photo-credit</theName> <value/> </rowAttribute> <rowAttribute> <theName>photo</theName> <value> <attachment id="4432434344"/> </value> </rowAttribute> </row></rows>]]></myphotos_grid>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml_string);
$xml_nodes = $doc->textContent;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_nodes);
$value = $xml->xpath('//rowAttribute/theName[contains(.,"photo-credit")]/following-sibling::value/text()')[0];
echo (string) $value; // my credit
```

Comment: It's not weird. In the input XML there is ***no*** `<value>` node. CDATA means character-date, which means all that is not parsed in there (but `]]>`). And the -1 is actually for the string manipulation as you can just read out the text verbatim and parse it as XML ... *sigh*.

Comment: @hakre i don't understand, the OP edited the xml and added a sample value inside the value node. `<theName>photo-credit</theName><value>my credit</value>`. in the original xml of course there is none. so what's the correct answer here? thanks

Comment: Also in the original XML, there was no `<value>` node, that was, before the OPs edit. Point in case here is the misconception that data in a CDATA block is not parsed as XML. I'd say this is important to highlight because that is the misconception of the OP. However I would more rate this as a typo then a programming question.